# Handle 2 routes to the same destination simultaneously

Tags: routing, nic, interface

I setup on my machine 2 different routes on 2 different interfaces to reach a single destination.

When I ping a machine on that destination network, the packet go through the route with the highest priority. Is there a way to send the packet to every route that reach that destination ?

I'm using ROS2 which automatically discard duplicated message. The idea is to have 2 ways to communicate with our cloud for reliability purpose. One via direct 4G on `eth1` and the other one via a ground-node (ip-radio) on `eth0` that is connected by Ethernet. The idea is to actually send messages to those 2 interfaces in the same time. Ideally, I need to read from them also at the same time.

Comment: crossposted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604939/handle-2-routes-to-the-same-destination-simultaneously . You're supposed to ask the question only once or delete it on the other place. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069